# Accepting all HTTP Requests to a certain method

Tags: java, rest, jersey, httprequest

I am using Jetty web server, and Jersey for REST handling.

I want that every HTTP request (which my server receives) which starts with /hqsim (no matter what comes later), for example `POST http://localhost:8080/hqsim/` will be directed to a certain method (the POST in my example).

Here is my code: I tried @Path("/"), @Path("*/"), and even not declaring any @Path but it does not work.

I want that every request will be directed  to the method `sendMessage`.

```
@Path("/hqsim")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class HQSimResource {
    // init class logger
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("audit."
            + HQSimResource.class.getName());

    @POST
    @Path("/*")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    public Response sendMessage(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo) {
        // logger.debug("/sendMessage");
        System.out.println("Received Post");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the @Path(/*) on the function level. the @Path(/hqsim) on the class level is enough.

A guess:
Usually the REST resources located under your web applications, something like: http://localhost:8080/myWebApplication/hqsim. Maybe this is the problem.

Second option is that you have a problem with your resource registration to Jersey.

Thanks,
Shay